# Unable to show JSON data from API on ag-grid using angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to fit data from backend into ag grid.

Below is my data from backend.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Sentence1"
}
```

This is the HTML where I am trying to throw the rowData inside ag-grid table.

```
<ag-grid-angular
    style= "border: 1pt, 1pt, 1pt, 1pt; overflow: auto; "
    class= "ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData] = "rowData"
    [columnDefs] = "columnDefs"
    rowSelection="multiple"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

I am able to print my backend data on my browser console but error below throws up when I am trying to fit my data into ag grid table.

```
this.DataService.getHello().subscribe(data => {
      this.rowData = data ;
      console.log(this.rowData);
    })
```

No rows coming up in my ag grid table.

> 

```
ERROR TypeError: rowData.map is not a function
    at ClientSideNodeManager.setRowData (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:46380:48)
    at ClientSideRowModel.setRowData (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:47222:26)
    at GridApi.setRowData (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:32300:41)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:7594:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ComponentUtil.processOnChange (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:7591:14)
    at AgGridAngular.ngOnChanges (ag-grid-angular.js:1514:13)
    at AgGridAngular.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:1510:1)
    at callHook (core.js:2548:1)
    at callHooks (core.js:2507:1)
```

Comment: `rowData` needs to be an array, you are passing a plain object. You need to change it in the BE or, in the FE, you can do: `this.rowData = [data] ;`

Comment: data added to rowData must be 1 array, please provide console.log(data) and getHello() function

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, it works now by wrapping data by square brackets. Thanks!